# Post final json nested array variables

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a add function where I add images to a campaign in a array called slots (each campaign has there own slots array).

Once added to the list I wish to post to an end point.

**Problem**

When I post I get back the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slots' of undefined
```

I need some help fixing this post, I cant see what the error is and how to fix it.

I am trying to post the current `campaign` and the `base_image`.

```
"campaign": ,
  "slots": [
    {
      "base_image": 
    }
  ]
```

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns" class="campaign-container">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{campaign.c_name}} {{$index}}</h1><strong>This Campaign you are allowed {{campaign.max_slots}}
        Images</strong>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select File</th>
                <th>Preview Image</th>
                <th>Add to list</th>
                <th>Images</th>
                <th>Save Campaign</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- UPLOAD IMAGE-->
                    <div class="upload-new">
                        <input type="file" fileread="vm.uploadme" id="fileinput-{{ $index }}"
                               onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)"/>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- PREVIEW IMAGE-->
                    <div class="preview">
                        <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{campaign.preview}}" alt="preview image">
                    </div>
                    <!-- END-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="addImage(campaign)">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size: 45px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <div ng-repeat="slot in campaign.slots" class="slot">
                        <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{slot.base_image}}" alt="show image here">
                        <button ng-click="removeImage(slot,campaign)">Remove Image</button>

                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="SaveImage()">
                        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size: 45px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.addImage = function (campaign) {
        // console.log('add in campaign', campaign);
        if (!campaign) {
            console.log('no campaign');
        }else {
            if (campaign.slots.length < campaign.max_slots) {
                campaign.slots.push({
                    "slot_id": $scope.length + 1,
                    "base_image": campaign.preview,
                    "path_image": ""
                });
            } else {
                window.alert("you have to delete a slot to generate a new one");
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.SaveImage = function (campaign) {
        // console.log($scope.campaigns[index].c_name);
        $http({
            url: "http://www.site.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/updateSlots",
            method: "POST",
            data: { 'slots': campaign.slots},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('success',response);
            window.alert("success, campaign has been saved");
        }, function (response) { // optional
            // failed
            console.log('failed', response);
        });
    };
```

Comment: How is bound/called `$scope.SaveImage` ?

Comment: Make it `campaign` accessible by `$scope.campaign`

Comment: @user2486 hmm did not work, i have updated the question to show the structure of my json

Comment: @NathanP. ill update the html now

Comment: I mean make a scope variable outside of method and then set or get by `$scope.campaign` instead of just `campaign`

Comment: It's the same issue, that I explained you in your previous question about half an hour ago. The function signatures in your JS and HTML need to match.

Comment: @PrerakSola That's at least the third question like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your binding to this :

```
<button ng-click="SaveImage(campaign)">
```